# Trying to align the text on top of the input box

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to align the text on top of the input box without manually aligning it. Any pointers on how to do this?

[image: refer]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="select-vehicle">
  <label for="exampleDataList" class="form-label">Select Plate number</label>
  <input class="select-vehicle-list" list="plate-number-list" id="exampleDataList" placeholder="Plate number">
  <datalist id="plate-number-list">
    <option value="San Francisco">
    <option value="New York">
    <option value="Seattle">
    <option value="Los Angeles">
    <option value="Chicago">
  </datalist>
</div>
```

Comment: there is no  `input box` in HTML  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Need HTML especially the classes

Comment: @zer00ne yeah I have updated the question.

Comment: @MisterJojo was talking about the input box (input tag) given in the picture attached

Comment: according to your image it is a `select`, and not a `text input` linked to a `list`

Comment: AND where are your Bootstrap css classes?

Comment: or a Button with dropdown

Comment: @MisterJojo in the reference image is an input tag with a drop-down I believe, as I was able to recreate it with the code I have given here. I merely want to know if there was a way to align the label in that way without manually positioning it.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "manual positioning".

Comment: @MisterJojo manually placing the label on top by giving relative positioning and padding. Like the alternative solution given in the accepted answer :))).

Comment: I needed a way to do it with or without bootstrap which the answer I validated provided. I guess maybe you didn't get my question, which is fine, but others have and I have got my answer. good day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using the `legend` tag

You can use the `fieldset` + `legend` combo to get a similar effect using pure CSS. See the snippet below:

```css
fieldset {
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: max-content;
  border: 1px solid #D4D4D5;
}

legend {
  font-size: 12px;
}

#exampleDataList {
  width: 15rem;
  border: none;
}

#exampleDataList:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Select Plate number</legend>

  <div class="select-vehicle">
    <input placeholder="Plate number" list="plate-number-list" id="exampleDataList">
    <datalist id="plate-number-list">
      <option value="San Francisco">
      <option value="New York">
      <option value="Seattle">
      <option value="Los Angeles">
      <option value="Chicago">
    </datalist>
  </div>

</fieldset>
```

### Alternative

You can give `label` a relative position and move it towards the position like in the picture you have given. See the snippet below:

```css
.select-vehicle {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.form-label {
  font-size: 12px;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  width: max-content;
  padding-inline: 5px;
  top: .5rem;
  left: .8rem;
}

#exampleDataList {
  width: 15rem;
  padding: .8rem 1rem;
  border: 1px solid #D4D4D5;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="select-vehicle">
  <label for="exampleDataList" class="form-label">Select Plate number</label>
  <input placeholder="Plate number" list="plate-number-list" id="exampleDataList">
  <datalist id="plate-number-list">
    <option value="San Francisco">
    <option value="New York">
    <option value="Seattle">
    <option value="Los Angeles">
    <option value="Chicago">
  </datalist>
</div>
```

More on css `position`s [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

Comment: thank you for this. but as mentioned in the question I wanted to know if there was a way to do this without aligning it manually. Something like the fieldset but for an input tag.

Comment: I see I did not read that. My bad. I'll give another alternative.

Comment: This is not Bootstrap 4 code...

Comment: Should the OP remove the `css` tag then?

Comment: @kaicr I've added another solution. See if it fulfills your requirement.

Comment: @MisterJojo I added a CSS tag too. Wanted to know all possibilities of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

In the title "legend" was mentioned and the pic resembles a `<fieldset>` and Bootstrap has foobared the fieldset to be unrecognizable. Here is the markup with BS classes for a fieldset that resembles a fieldset:

```
<fieldset class="border rounded p-2">
  <legend class="float-none w-auto"></legend>
</fieldset>
```

I added `.h6` and `.mb-0` to the `<legend>` to decrease both `font-size` and `margin-bottom`. Are you sure you need a `<label>` or are you adding more form controls to the fieldset?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style></style>
</head>

<body>
  <main class="container">
    <section class="row">
      <form>
        <fieldset class="border rounded p-2">
          <legend class="float-none w-auto mb-0 h6">Select State of Registeration: </legend>
          <input id='state' name="state" class="form-control" list="state-list" placeholder='State'>
          <datalist id="state-list">
                <option value="San Francisco">
                <option value="New York">
                <option value="Seattle">
                <option value="Los Angeles">
                <option value="Chicago">
            </datalist>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </section>
  </main>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I have tried something similar to this but this adds the label to an outer fieldset element right. but i wanted to align the label on top of the input tag itself similar to the fieldset, if that makes sense